# Form disappears in Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, forms, firefox, html-table, submit

I am very new to building websites, ie. I taught myself last week from scratch. I've designed a theme and uploaded it to Wordpress via cpanel. The website looks great in Chrome, but my submit buttons and form are missing in IE and all tables are completely wrong in Firefox.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Here is my website: http://bespokecook.co.uk/

Website content is incomplete as it is for a friends new company.

I really appreciate any suggestions at all...

```
<div id="content">
<table id="contactform">
<tr>
<td class="form" ROWSPAN="2">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php _e('oops... Sorry this page cannot be found'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
<form method="post" action="mailto:katy.wooff@bhwt.co.uk?Subject=Enquiry from bespokecook.co.uk" >
    <input class="contactform" required="required" type="text" name="Your-name" placeholder="Your name*">
    <input class="contactform" required="required" type="text" name="Your-surname" placeholder="Your surname*">
    <input class="contactform" required="required" type="tel" name="Telephone" placeholder="Telephone*">
    <input class="contactform" required="required" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email*">
    <div id="scroll-bar"><textarea class="contactform" maxlength="2000" spellcheck="true" name="textarea" rows="15" cols="100" placeholder="Anything else you'd like to tell us?"></textarea></div>
<p>*This field is required</p>
<a href="http://bespokecook.co.uk/contact"><input align="left" value="Send Email" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND US YOUR PLANS"></a>
</td>
</form>
<td class="jim-no" ROWSPAN="2"></td>
<td class="sidebar-1"><a><img class="aligncenter" src="http://bespokecook.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/IMG_7454.jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="sidebar">
<h4>Telephone</h4>
<p>07754 626113</p>
<h4>Email</h4>
<a href="mailto:hello@bespokecook.co.uk?Subject=Enquiry from bespokecook.co.uk" target="_top"<p>hello@bespokecook.co.uk</p></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post the code that doesnt seem to work accross all browsers

Comment: Yup! I know! Cannot work out how to fix that either...

Comment: Can you the post the `<form>` along with the `<input>` for the submit buttons

Comment: That's the `CSS` code? I meant the `html` code

Comment: That's still `CSS` maybe your code isn't appearing because you don't have any? You did say you just started last week. This code you're posting doesn't output anything on the webpage other than how something looks, `CSS` is for styling buttons/forms whatever else. So in order to have a form or button, go watch some `HTML5` videos.. EDIT: You updated with right code

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, hope there is a solution! I'm determined to not be defeated and have to use a pre-made wordpress theme!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I do not see a tag ending your `<form>` unless I just looked over it 10 times. To end a `<form>` use `</form>` . Second you have a an href with your button, to do this, `<a href="http://www.example.com/"> <button>Whatever</button> </a>` , that's an example. From what I read it looked like you actually wanted a `submit button` . In order to do that, you need to learn `PHP` `if statements` , you should include the button in your form. The statement will be like `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` that's an example, you will NEED it. If you don't have it, it won't work. It'll just be for looks and clicking, will not do anything. I also noticed you had two `values` in the `input` for the `submit button` your `value` should just be `submit` you'll need it. If you want long text, use a `button` . `<button>Button tags</button` . I posted it in a comment, I'll put it in the answer as well. IE doesn't recognize `placeholder`, so it won't show any fields.

Comment: @Katy I see the ending `</form>` tag now. Also forgot to mention, IE doesn't recognize `placeholder` so it won't show anything.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll digest all of that, thanks. There is a </form> in there after the textarea. At the moment the submit button loads all the fields into an outlook email, which is not ideal and defeats the object of a form. So PHP is my next challenge. I'll make your changes, still not sure if that will help the submit to display in IE. Thanks again :) EDIT: thank you for the extra notes!!

Comment: Do you know what I could use to make IE recognise the input?

Comment: @Katy Try `<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">` for your submit button and tell me if that shows. Submit it outside of your `<form>` at first to see if it shows up.

Comment: Yup will do first thing tomorrow! Thank you @David

Comment: I get a grey box, but only when I place it outside of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Part of good web code development is checking for HTML markup errors. So I'd first fix your code errors; see [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  bespokecook.co.uk  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//bespokecook.co.uk/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). The W3C Markup Validator is a great tool to use; the service also offers CSS validations, and other services.

Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. You're missing a Doctype (which throws versions of IE into quirks mode), have duplicate div id's, and a missing closing `</form>` tag. The missing `alt` tags errors are minor and don't impact display. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.

And, learn to use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see how to work with and change HTML, as well as CSS and check for Javascript errors (none currently). Dev tools are invaluable for theme and web development.